# TypeScript typing for dynamic react context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a new context
`export const SchemaContext = React.createContext(null);`

object of context create into component which get prop which will be a part of context.

```
type TSchemaProps<M = {}}> = {
  model: M
};


export const Schema = <M,>({
  model: globalModel
}: TSchemaProps<M>) => {
  const [model] = useState<M>(globalModel);

  const context = {
    model,
    isRoot: true
  };

  return (
    <SchemaContext.Provider value={context}> // Type { model: M } is not assignable to null
      {children}
    </SchemaContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and now we can use JSX generic for typing

```
type TModel = {
    docNum: number,
    docDate: number,
    group: {
        kpp: string,
        orgn: string
    }
};

const MainComp = () => {
  <Schema<TModel> />
}
```

How can i pass TModel into context type?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass in a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to `createContext` when the context is generated to define the type of its values.

```
type TModel = {
    docNum: number,
    docDate: number,
    group: {
        kpp: string,
        orgn: string
    }
};

...

export const MyContext = createContext<TModel | SomeOtherType>(defaultValues);
```

Comment: i can use some `Models` but one `Context`

Comment: What do you mean?  You can use any type or interface you want, you just need to pass it as a generic to ```createContext```.

Comment: i dont know which interface i will use exactly. Can i change interface or type in `Schema` component? Something like that `const Context = MyContext.Consumer as M`?

Comment: You'd need to either pass in multiple types, or build a type that accounts for all the data you may need.  I updated my answer to show how you could use 2 different types.  I recommend reading up on [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) and [intersection types](https://codingblast.com/typescript-intersection-types/), as these are separate topics.

Comment: So if I have 1000 model, I need to write 1000 intersection or create 1000 context with different model, right?

Comment: If you have x number of totally different types that you're passing into the same context? Yes, you'd need to account for them somehow if you want them to be typechecked, but that doesn't sound like a reasonable use case. Why on earth would you have so many different data types, especially in one location? If you don't care about typechecking you're not forced to provide a generic type at all.

Comment: Because I write typings for library which use recursive creating context. For example `<Schema<TModel>><Schema<TAnotherModel>></Schema></Schema>` it have more complicated logic just creating context.

Comment: I see. If you want it to be variable, you can use a generic at the component level.  It's tough to give you an example without seeing the component, but you could pass in a generic of T and then use ```createContext<T>()```. You can see an overview of what I mean [here](https://dev.to/busypeoples/-notes-on-typescript-react-and-generics-35c9).